# Fullcalendar Year View

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, laravel-5.3

In Fullcalendar can we get a view of all month in a single View(Year View) with days clickable in laravel
**than using seperate div's for each month**

Comment: Did you check custom views option?  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/

Comment: [link](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/1140) i found a patch here...thnx brother...i am now trying it...

Comment: @SalindaKrish, did you able to solve it?